# XSD Validation on integer 0001 or 000

Tags: java, eclipse, xsd, xsd-validation

In my application, we use XSD validation to check whether the given text input is a number greater or equal to 0. This works fine, but when we enter numbers like 000 or 001 it validates it too. So when we write to a file it writes the 000 and 001 but we want to not validate them. We want them as 0 or 1, not 000 or 001.

How can we enable it and trim the 00 at the beginning? Is there an XSD type or restriction for it?

How can we solve this issue?

Comment: Giving error for inputs that start with 0 is also welcome. So 0020000 is not a valid number and give XSD Validation error for it.

Comment: Your question could be improved. It is not clear whether you want to disallow leading zeroes when parsing or when writing. Or is it both?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you only want to validate the content given to write or read from the files or also alter it. the xml schema cannot alter the data. Assuming the to be validated content is of the type string. You can use a regex pattern to check if the content is correct. the below example gives checks if the last character in the string is 0 or 1 and all the characters prior to it must be 0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="input">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:pattern value="(0*[0-1])?[0-1]"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**update after receiving comments**

if you only want to approve the xml structure that has a single digit in the range of 0 to 9 you can use the below example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="input">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: XSD validates 00001 but I want to give error when it is 001, 002, 003 ... 000 I dont want leading zeros. I want XSD give error when it is 001, when not 1...

Comment: I want the element should be integer as well.

Comment: so you want an element of the type xs:int that only allows numbers from 0 to 9 for 1 digit? or only 0 or 1?

Comment: type xs:int that only allows numbers from 0 to 9 for 1 digit. I want to give error for 0005 which is 5 normally.